# How to duplicate div on click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a `div` to be duplicated after itself when a `button` is clicked. I found *JS* solutions but I need a *jQuery* one and I'm really bad at it.
Can anyone help me please?

**That's what I have:**

```
<div class="example-1">
  <div class="example-2"> 
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>

    <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**That's what I need (after *click*):**

```
<div class="example-1">
  <div class="example-2"> 
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>

    <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
  </div>

  <div class="example-2"> 
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>

    <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to try. You can't learn if someone will provide you codes. https://api.jquery.com/clone/ http://api.jquery.com/after/ http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make use of `.clone()` to copy the div and `.after()` to append. Since you are using class you may want to copy only one div, in that case you should use `.closest()`. Also  you need to pass a boolean parameter to clone so that all data and event handlers will be attached to cloned element.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".btn-copy").on('click', function(){
    var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
    $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-1">
  <div class="example-2"> 
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>

    <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for answer but Copy `button` should work in duplicated `div` too and duplicate correct `div`. Not the first one.

Comment: Edited the answer. Check it

Comment: seems right. button duplicate block in which has been pressed?

Comment: That the reason I used closest and after. Does it solve your problem now.

Answer (score 3):

***updated***

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('button').click(function (){
        $('.example-1').append($('.example-1').html())
    
        //console.log($('.example-1').html());
    })
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-1">
  <div class="example-2"> 
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>
<button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
    
</div>

<!--its only print at once-->
```

Comment: Thx for answer but Copy `button` should work in duplicated `div` too. And `button` must clone only one `div` in the end of last one.

Comment: Nope. `button` must be in every `div` that we duplicate.

Comment: clone button also work with a same clone  event right

Comment: Example: (block 1 with button) on click we will get (second block with button too. first block remains unchanged) now we can click button in first block to copy it or button in second block to copy second. Sry, its hard to me to explain the idea in English

Comment: when click the button it will get the data with in a block only .`First block button => first_data` . `second block button=> second_data`

Comment: Yeah, thats how it must work. In ur current code only 1 button work and copy all blocks thats were duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```js
$('.btn-copy').click(function ()
{
$('.example-1').append($('.example-2').html());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-1">
  <div class="example-2"> 
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>

    <button class="btn-copy" >Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for answer but Copy `button` should work in duplicated `div` too and duplicate correct `div`. Not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clone` method for this. Like this:

```
$(document).on(click,'.btn-copy',function(){
  $(this).parents('.example-1').append($(this).parent().clone());
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<BODY>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-copy").click(function(event){
    console.log('You clicked button');
    var parentnode=this.parentNode;
    var OuterHtml=parentnode.outerHTML;
    var TopLevel=parentnode.parentNode;
    $(TopLevel).append(OuterHtml);
  });
});
</script>
<div class="example-1">
  <div class="example-2">
    <p>Example one</p>
    <p>Example two</p>
    <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```