# How to duplicate a div on a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the '+' button to be clicked and it would append another name field beneath the first name field.

```js
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i;
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="duplicater">
  <div class="columns-5 w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <label for="Contact-Name" class="field-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-round w-input"
               maxlength="256" name="Contact-Name-1"
               data-name="Contact Name 1" id="Contact-Name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button" onclick=duplicate() class="button button5 btn-">+</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate div on click with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276001/how-to-duplicate-div-on-click-with-jquery)

Comment: Use the method setAttribute of the document model to set id and also wrap ++i in ().

Comment: it seems to be working, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @CharleneVas altought is the same question, here OP didn't tag `jQuery`, so it cannot be a duplicate of a question that uses the jq

Comment: People don't seem to appreciate my anwser so I deleted it, but here is how I could archive the same in the most simple vanilla javascript code : https://jsfiddle.net/wlarch/mh8js6uk/9/

Comment: @wlarcheveque my guess is -- your answer was in terms of jQuery, and the question is not tagged jquery, and doesn't use it in the sample code. The "possible duplicate" **_is_** about jquery, and Calvin Nunes' comments that he doesn't think it's a dupe because this question is _not_ about jquery. An answer for this question should be vanilla JS.  Maybe you should post your vanilla fiddle as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

the question seems to me really badly asked, here is the answer for this I could understand:

```js
const duplicate1 = document.getElementById('duplicater-1')
    , BigParent  = duplicate1.parentNode
    , BtDuplicat = document.getElementById('bt-Duplik')


BtDuplicat.onclick=_=>
  {
  let Clone   = duplicate1.cloneNode(true)
    , D_nb    = document.querySelectorAll('.DupliX').length +1
    , inClone = Clone.querySelector('input')

  Clone.id                    = 'duplicater-'+D_nb
  inClone.id =  inClone.name  = 'Contact-Name-'+D_nb
  inClone.dataset.name        = 'Contact Name '+D_nb

  BigParent.insertBefore(Clone, BtDuplicat)
  }
```

```html
<div id="duplicater-1" class="DupliX">
  <div class="columns-5 w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
      <label class="field-label">Name
        <input type="text" id="Contact-Name-1" name="Contact-Name-1" data-name="Contact Name 1"
              maxlength="256"  class="input-round w-input" >
      </label>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="bt-Duplik" class="button button5 btn-">+</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're only looking to add a single extra field under the first one, it might be a better option to have the second field built in already. You can style it with display: none, and then when the button is clicked change the style to display: block.

```js
var duplicate = document.getElementById('duplicater2');
function reveal() {
  duplicate.style = "display: block;";
}
```

```html
<div id="duplicater">
  <div class="columns-5 w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6"><label for="Contact-Name" class="field-label">Name</label><input type="text" class="input-round w-input" maxlength="256" name="Contact-Name-1" data-name="Contact Name 1" id="Contact-Name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="duplicater2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="columns-5 w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6"><label for="Contact-Name" class="field-label">Name</label><input type="text" class="input-round w-input" maxlength="256" name="Contact-Name-2" data-name="Contact Name 2" id="Contact-Name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="reveal()" >Button</button>
```